# longtable in same page

Tags: longtable

How to write a long table within a single page?

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{ The approximate solutions  }
    \label{tab:1}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        & A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
        \hline
        $y$&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$u$}\\
        \hline
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
       $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        \hline
        $x$&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$v$}\\
        \hline
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
       $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6\\
        $0$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        $1$ &62& -0.06&11  &6 \\
        \hline      
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: you have not actually asked a question what is the problem you have with the code posted? It is better to post a complete small document that people can run to see any issues. You have tagged the question longtable but have not used that package (and that is for multi-page tables)

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. The question contained in the title of your posting would appear to be already answered -- by the code you provided. Are you maybe planning to place the two halves of the `tabular` environment side by side? Please rephrase the question.

Comment: Use [htp] instead of [H].  In fact, try to forget [H] exists.